# Facing column disorientation(jumbling of data from one cell to another cell horizontally, irregular column width issue) in HTML format table

Tags: html, shell, csv

I'm trying to convert input csv file(**dynamic**: no. of columns & rows can vary) into html table using shell script.

**input CSV**(no. of columns & rows can vary):

```
Id,Employee,Task,Status,Date
5303,Mancha,Testing,Failure,20-20-20
2532,Mari,Requirement,Success,20-20-20
```

**Code written**:

```
csv_to_html()
{
report_html=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";
            print "<html><head><style>"
            print "table, tr, td {font-family : Tahoma, sans-serif; border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 12px; width: 100%;}"
            print ".green {background-color: #98FB98; color:black}"
            print ".red {background-color: #F08088; color:black}"
            print ".grey {background-color: #C0C0C0; color:black}"
            print ".white {background-color: #FFFFF; color:black}"
            print "<body><table>"
            
NR == 1 {   print "<tr bgcolor=\"#87CEFA\"; width: 100%>";
            for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print "<td><b>" $i "</b></td>";
               print "</tr>"}
NR > 1  {   print "<tr width: 100%;>";
            for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
               print "<td" (" class=" ($i=="Failure"?"red":$i=="Sucess"?"green":$i=="NONE"?"#FFFFE0":"white")) ">" $i "</td>";
               print "</tr>")
END     {print "</table></body></html>"}'              
}
```

**Required Html Table**:
[Output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCyYT.png)

It works fine for certain input files, but when it encounters other csv files it produces html table  with column disorientation (jumbling of data from one cell to another cell horizontally, irregular column width etc). I'm thinking its due to increased length of strings in certain csv file.

PS: I'm new to html please help me resolve this issue

Comment: You have to decide, either I will accept just any junk data (and write an ever more complicated set of programming solutions to deal with that) OR I will limit my tables to mirror data that is in a standardized format. (This is the normal expectation when working in industry (unless crappy data is your specialty) ). As a compromise, I'd recommend that you write one "system" (input->processing->html) per source. Do the "easy" ones first, and work on others as  you understand better how to deal with exceptions. ....

Comment: IMHO, data in `.csv` files is  an implied contract from the provider that it will be consistent and already cleaned, but your case may be different. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, could you please post expected sample output also in your question to make it more clear, Thank you.

Comment: I added the screenshot of required HTML table at the end

Comment: _when it encounters other csv files_  : You did not give an example of a CSV file which produces incorrect output. Since you make no attempt into parsing a general CSV file, it is obviously possible to generate a syntactically valid CSV, which your program can not handle. But if you can ensure that the input you receive is always generated to be compatible to the CSV subset you are parsing here, you don't need a full parser. Therefore check the input for the faulty cases.